# Blockquote class doesn't show lines in Bootstrap 4 Beta 3

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have two simple blockquote HTML elements. I added Bootstrap blackquote class and expected bigger font with lines. However, the fonts become bigger but the lines don't appear at all.

HTML section where I use the blockquote elements.

```
<section>

        <blockquote class="blockquote">
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
        </blockquote>

        <blockquote class="blockquote">
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
            Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.
        </blockquote>

    </section>
```

I tried blockquote classes with different Bootstrap releases. The lines immediately appeared when I changed from Beta to Alpha release. Bootstrap 4 Beta 3 doesn't, however, show the lines. Am I doing something wrong or have the lines been dropped from the blackquote class in the Beta releases?

Comment: What lines? Do you have an image?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
<section>
  <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
    <p class="mb-0"> Text for the blockquote. Text for the blockquote.</p>
    <footer class="blockquote-footer">Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
  </blockquote> 
</section>
```

Check out my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Codewife_101/pen/qpKpNe?editors=1100).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bootstrap css was properly link to your html.

```
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
```